# docker: Error: failed to remove one or more images

Tags: docker

I am not able to remove this image `docker run -p 8080:80 bgruening/galaxy-stable`

```
$ sudo docker ps -a -q
69a86acd37be
87540cb4904e
5c3e20ad2159
1426b69a9709
2cba8dcddd66
52b492693f21

$ sudo docker rmi 52b492693f21
Error response from daemon: No such image: 52b492693f21
FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

How can I remove this image?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are listing the containers and trying to remove a container. Use `docker images` to list all the images and remove it with `docker rmi IMAGEID` with the proper id. If your intention is remove a container, not an image, use `docker rm CONTAINERID`

Answer (score 0):

run the wrong command to list docker images, it should be:

```
docker images
```

then you should be fine to remove the images with `docker rmi`

But before to do that, make sure, the related containers all cleaned already.

```
docker ps -a 
docker rm -f XXXXXX  # -f means force removed if some of them are still in run mode.
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, I think that you want to stop and remove a container after you run it `docker run -p 8080:80 bgruening/galaxy-stable`

So you should run 2 commands below:

```
sudo docker stop 52b492693f21
sudo docker rm 52b492693f21
```

If you need to remove a image, you should use commands `docker images` to list all images, and `docker rmi` to remove a image.
Hope it helps